# NetCDF 500 metres shifted and unknown PCS

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, gdal, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I'm trying to merge 12 GeoTIFFs monthly files (ETRS_1989_LAEA, EPSG:3035) to NetCDF as following:

```
    import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
from osgeo import gdal
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
import os
import re


file_define_shape = 'C:\datiGIS/netcdf/2020/st_09/2020_01_st_09.tif'
dir_to_process = 'C:\datiGIS/netcdf/2020/st_09'
regex_files = '[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_st_09.tif' # ~year / ~month params
outputFile = 'C:\datiGIS/netcdf/2020/st_09/st_09_2020_3035.nc'

today = date.today()
date_created = today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
dataset = gdal.Open(file_define_shape)
a = dataset.ReadAsArray()

ny, nx = np.shape(a)

transform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
xOrigin = transform[0]
yOrigin = transform[3]
pixelWidth = transform[1]
pixelHeight = transform[5]

x = np.arange(nx) * pixelWidth + xOrigin
y = np.arange(ny) * pixelHeight + yOrigin

basedate = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
nco = netCDF4.Dataset(outputFile, 'w', clobber=True)

# check http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/blogs/developer/entry/chunking_data_choosing_shapes
chunk_x = 48
chunk_y = 21
chunk_time = 1

# create dimensions, variables and attributes:
nco.createDimension('x', nx)
nco.createDimension('y', ny)
nco.createDimension('time', None)

time_v = nco.createVariable('time', 'f4', ('time'))
time_v.units = 'days since 1970-1-1 00:00:00'
time_v.standard_name = 'time'
time_v.calendar = 'gregorian'

x_v = nco.createVariable('x', 'f4', ('x'))
x_v.units = 'm'
x_v.standard_name = 'projection_x_coordinate'
x_v.long_name = 'x coordinate of projection'
x_v.axis = 'X'

y_v = nco.createVariable('y', 'f4', ('y'))
y_v.units = 'm'
y_v.standard_name = 'projection_y_coordinate'
y_v.long_name = 'y coordinate of projection'
y_v.axis = 'Y'

crs_v = nco.createVariable('crs', 'i4')
crs_v.long_name = 'Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area'
crs_v.grid_mapping_name = 'lambert_azimuthal_equal_area'
crs_v.longitude_of_projection_origin = 10.0
crs_v.latitude_of_projection_origin = 52.0
crs_v.false_easting = 4321000.0
crs_v.false_northing = 3210000.0
crs_v.esri_pe_string = 'PROJCS[\'ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe\',GEOGCS[\'ETRS89\',DATUM[\'European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989\',SPHEROID[\'GRS 1980\',6378137,298.257222101],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],PRIMEM[\'Greenwich\',0],UNIT[\'degree\',0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\'EPSG\',\'9122\']],AUTHORITY[\'EPSG\',\'4258\']],PROJECTION[\'Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area\'],PARAMETER[\'latitude_of_center\',52],PARAMETER[\'longitude_of_center\',10],PARAMETER[\'false_easting\',4321000],PARAMETER[\'false_northing\',3210000],UNIT[\'metre\',1],AUTHORITY[\'EPSG\',\'3035\']]'


vd_v = nco.createVariable('vd', 'f4', ('time', 'y', 'x'),
                          zlib=True, chunksizes=[chunk_time, chunk_y, chunk_x], fill_value=-9999.)
vd_v.units = 'seconds'
vd_v.long_name = 'Vessel density'
vd_v.missing_value = -9999.
vd_v.grid_mapping = 'crs'
vd_v.set_auto_maskandscale(False)

nco.Conventions = 'CF-1.8'
nco.title = 'Vessel Density'
nco.history = 'created by Cogea.'
nco.version = 'Version 1.0'
nco.website = 'https://emodnet.ec.europa.eu'
nco.date_created = date_created
nco.creator_name = 'Alessandro Pititto'
nco.creator_email = 'apititto@cogea.it'
nco.institution = 'Cogea'
nco.note = 'Merging multiple GeoTIFFS to NetCDF'

x_v[:] = x
y_v[:] = y

itime = 0
prog = re.compile(regex_files)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_to_process):
    dirs.sort()
    files.sort()
    for f in files:
        if re.match(prog, f):
            year = int(f[0:4])
            month = int(f[5:7])
            date = dt.datetime(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0) # first day of the month
            diff_time = (date - basedate).total_seconds() / 86400.0
            time_v[itime] = diff_time
            f_path = os.path.join(root, f)
            dataset_temp = gdal.Open(f_path)
            a = dataset_temp.ReadAsArray()
            vd_v[itime] = a
            itime = itime + 1

nco.close()
```

Rhe result loaded in ArcMap is a NetCDF file with 12 correct time dimension values but with the following issues:

1. Rhe NetCDF (deep blue) is 500 metres shifted from the original GeoTIFF (light blue) and from the reference grid (see image, a cell is 1x1 km)
   [image];
2. The datum is WGS84 while should be ETRS_1989

[image];

3. Unknow Units

[image];

4. The layer extension is 500 metres different among the GeoTIFF

[image]

and the NetCDF

[image];

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The geotransform of you GTiff describes the outer bounds of the dataset (and the pixels), while the coordinates in a netCDF refer to the pixel centers. So when you do this it should work.

```
xOrigin = transform[0]
yOrigin = transform[3]
pixelWidth = transform[1]
pixelHeight = transform[5]

x = np.arange(nx) * pixelWidth + xOrigin + 0.5 * pixelWidth
y = np.arange(ny) * pixelHeight + yOrigin - 0.5 * pixelHeight
```

Comment: Thank you! I have modified your suggestion by adding 0.5 to y instead of subtracting and the netcdf is now in the correct position  and also the extent is correct. 
y = np.arange(ny) * pixelHeight + yOrigin + 0.5 * pixelHeight. I get still unkonwn units and uncorrect datum